# React production build: Cannot read property 'listenBeforeLeavingRoute' of undefined

Tags: webpack, react-router, redux

My code is working as expected when I use webpack with my dev config file. But with the production one, I get this error when loading the resulting build in the browser.

This error occurs in `RouterUtils` of `react-router` which is called by `redux-router`.

As you can guess, I quite new with webpack, and React things.

Production file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

// App files location
const PATHS = {
  app: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/js'),
  styles: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles'),
  images: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/images'),
  build: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')
};

const plugins = [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
      from: PATHS.images,
      to: 'images'
    }
  ]),
  // Shared code
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'js/vendor.bundle.js'),
  // Avoid publishing files when compilation fails
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || 'false'))
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
      warnings: false
    }
  }),
  // This plugin moves all the CSS into a separate stylesheet
  new ExtractTextPlugin('css/app.css', { allChunks: true })
];

const sassLoaders = [
  'css-loader?sourceMap',
  'postcss-loader',
  'sass-loader?outputStyle=compressed'
];

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(PATHS.app, 'main.js'),
    vendor: ['react']
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true
  },
  resolve: {
    // We can now require('file') instead of require('file.jsx')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.css'],

    alias: {
      'rc-time-picker/assets/index.css': path.resolve('./node_modules/rc-time-picker/assets/index.css'),
      'emojione-picker/css/picker.css': path.resolve('./node_modules/emojione-picker/css/picker.css'),
      'react-mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-css/mapbox-gl.css': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-css/mapbox-gl.css')
    }
  },
  externals: {
    'layer-sdk': 'layer'
  },
  module: {
    noParse: /\.min\.js$/,
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
        include: PATHS.app
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!'))
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader')
      },
      // Inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=images/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    })];
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Development file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

// App files location
const PATHS = {
  app: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/js'),
  styles: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles'),
  build: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')
};

const plugins = [
  // Shared code
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'js/vendor.bundle.js'),
  // Avoid publishing files when compilation fails
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || 'false'))
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin()
];

const sassLoaders = [
  'style-loader',
  'css-loader?sourceMap',
  'postcss-loader',
  'sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded'
];

module.exports = {
  env : process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(PATHS.app, 'main.js'),
    vendor: ['react']
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true
  },
  resolve: {
    // We can now require('file') instead of require('file.jsx')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
  },
  externals: {
    'layer-sdk': 'layer'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
        include: PATHS.app
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: sassLoaders.join('!')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader'
      },
      // Inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    })];
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    port: 3000
  },
  devtool: 'eval'
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well my issue was that I forgot to include ReduxReactRouter inside the compose function in my store, in the production condition.

```
enhancer = compose(middleware, reduxReactRouter({ routes, createHistory }));
```

I doubt anyone will have the same issue, but I prefer to solve it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while learning about react routing.

In my Server.js file, where I call the ReactRouter.match(..) to wire up my routes, I forgot to check for renderProperties before calling the react-dom/server function renderToString.

So `renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);` was receiving an undefined renderProps.